# Getting callbacks for mouseovers over any control in a silverlight page?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

I have a control in silverlight and what I'd like it to know is if the mouse hovers over an entirely seperate control somewhere else on the xaml page.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In xaml for `UserControl` where your elements placed add trigger for `MouseMoveHandler`. Within this trigger do something like:

```
var position = e.GetPosition(null);
var elements = VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates(position, sender);
var Items = from element in elements
            where element is DesiredElement
            select element;
```

And do whatever you want with this item.

*Hope, it will help you.*

Comment: am I only one who thinks that performance of this can be pretty bad?

Comment: @ValentinKuzub, you're right. That is just one of the way for solving problem. It depend on size and objectives pursued by author.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you need it can be done like this:

In your control create a method like

```
SubscribeToMouseEvents(FrameworkElement other)
{
 other.MouseEnter += MouseEnterHandler;
 other.MouseMove += MouseMoveHandler;
 other.MouseLeave += MouseLeaveHandler;
}
```

If this is not what you need please elaborate question more